# How to Customize react-bootstrap-typeahead to remove the default filtering of case-insensitive string match.

Tags: react-bootstrap

As per the documentation, I see that the library provides a filterBy prop. But I need to use it to remove the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: As of v0.10.0, you can set `caseSensitive=true` to make filtering case-sensitive.

It would be helpful if you provided more information about the behavior you're trying to achieve. Based on your description, it sounds like you want case-sensitive filtering. To do this, pass a callback function to the `filterBy` prop:

```
<Typeahead
  labelKey="yourLabelKey"
  filterBy={option => (
    option['yourLabelKey'].indexOf(this.state.text) !== -1;
  )}
  onInputChange={text => this.setState({text})}
/>
```

See [the documentation](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/Filtering.md) for more info.